# Is it possible to add these two matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, definition

$A=\begin{pmatrix}
2 & 5 & -3\\ 
0 &-1 & 6
\end{pmatrix}$

$B=\begin{pmatrix}
3 & 1\\ 
4 & -2\\ 
0 & 6
\end{pmatrix}$, $A,B \in \mathbb{R}$

Is $A+B$ possible?

I have tried it on paper but I cannot decide how it could be done correctly : /

So now I'm wondering if this is possible defined at all?

By the way, would it be possible to do $A+1$ when $1 \in \mathbb{R}$

Comment: $A,B\in\mathbb{R}$? ?

Comment: @Jack both are real matrices

Comment: No. One would never ever use a notation in that way.

Comment: There is a good question at the heart of this.  But @Jack has hit upon your main misconception already.  You could meaningfully compute $A+B^{T} $ but why would you want to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not. The rule for matrix addition is element-wise. You can multiply them though!

Comment: Thanks!!!! Would A+1 work? Because only one element and we can imagine the other as zero so same size?

Comment: Not unless $A$ happened to be a 1 by 1 matrix. If you mean a matrix with 1 in the first entry and zeros everywhere else, you should just write that so as to avoid confusing people.

Answer (score 1):

You're confusing things: $A,B$ are **not** $\in\Bbb{R}$. The numbers in $A,B$ **are** $\in \Bbb{R}$. The notation you are employing to say that those are real matrices does not exist in - at least - *decent* literature on the subject.

In the standard way the summation of matrices is defined ,which is based on sum of linear transformations, you can't sum that two matrices. Also, If $1$ is a number in $\Bbb{R}$, you can't sum it with a matrix unless you define it in some meaningful way.

I recommend you to review matrix operations. You can use anything on the internet, perhaps Khan academy. If you need a book, take Lang's: Introduction to Linear Algebra.

Answer (score 1):

I think Ken Kuttler in his book [A First Course in Linear Algebra](http://lyryx.com/lscs/Kuttler-LinearAlgebra-AFirstCourse-2014A.pdf) (2014) puts it quite well. I'll refer to Definition 2.5 on page 61

> *Let $A = [a_{ij}]$ and $B = [b{ij} ]$ be two $m × n$ matrices. Then $A + B = C$ where $C$ is the $m × n$ matrix $C = [c_{ij} ]$ defined by
> $$c_{ij} = a_{ij} + b_{ij}$$*

When rows and columns are of the same size, we are able to preform Matrix addtion. Eitherwise it is not possible.